# JNI, error when using two .so files where one needs the other

Tags: java, c++, tomcat, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have two `.so` files - `A.so` and `B.so`, where `A.so` needs `B.so`.

I use `System.setProperty("java.library.path","thePath");`

and I check `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Then I load `A.so` using `System.load("/absolutePath/A.so");`

`A.so` and `B.so` are in the same directory.

The error I get is that `B.so can not find`.

I can not use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

`ldd A.so` shows `B.so => ./B.so`

I also use `System.loadLibrary("A");` but the error is that `A can not find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution may be:

Let `ldd` shows the absolute path.

Edit the `CMakeList.txt` file:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/the/absolute/path/")

target_link_libraries(A B.so)
```

---

UPDATE:

Find the way, I only give the whole cmake file example.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(xgbtSimiCalcer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -fpermissive -m64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -O3 -march=native")

SET(xgbtSimiCalcer_SRC test0.cpp ../test1.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(./)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\\$ORIGIN")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../model/")
LINK_LIBRARIES("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../test.so")
ADD_LIBRARY(xgbtSimiCalcer SHARED ${xgbtSimiCalcer_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(xgbtSimiCalcer m.so dl.so pthread.so)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "../../tmp")
SET(INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../model_")
INSTALL(TARGETS xgbtSimiCalcer LIBRARY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_DIR})
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.library.path` is only used for libraries loaded directly from Java. Dependency libraries will only be found if the operating system itself can find them.
If you cannot use LD_LIBRARY_PATH and B is not in the system search path you have to load B explicitly before A with its absolute path. Then the operating system will find it in the process memory.